# How to get all arguments in variable argument method?

Tags: c++, c

I have a variable argument function called from ruby script as follows:

```
static myMethod(VALUE exc, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  // Implementation of myMethod which requires all the arguments 
  // how to access the all arguments.
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to access all the arguments.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Choose between C and C++. In C++11, you would switch to variadic templates and ditch the varargs.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: How does one call a C++ variadic template from Ruby?

Comment: @Hasturkun: I don't know Ruby... Still a C++ variable template will generate a mangled name for each combination of parameters, so if you can identify the name, you can then call it (using the appropriate convention) from assembly... all that matter afterwards is having the right wrapper, but once again, I don't know Ruby :)

Comment: @MatthieuM Thanks for hlep, im using C++.

Answer (score 5):

What does "access the all arguments" mean? You can access the variadic arguments one by one by using macros from `va_...` group (`va_start`, `va_arg` etc.), the way it is usually done.

Comment: can u provide the code to access that arguments, I called the function with following arguments, myMethod(exception, "hi this first arg", "this is second arg" "THirt arg" 100)

Comment: @Prajkata: There's no way to determine the number and the types of arguments from inside `myMethod`. You have to manually pass that information from the outside. For example `printf` uses its first parameter (format string) for that purpose. You also have `fmt`, which is probably supposed to serve the same purpose. Again, you have to develop a way to pass the number and the types of arguments. Before that nothing meaningful can be done.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, the variadic templates have been introduced, which allow a type safe alternative for variadic functions.

The typical example is a variant of the traditional `printf`, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_templates):

```
void printf(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%')
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid format string: missing arguments");
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printf(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
    while (*s) {
        if (*s == '%' && *(++s) != '%') {
            std::cout << value;
            ++s;
            printf(s, args...); // call even when *s == 0 to detect extra arguments
            return;
        }
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
    throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}
```

Note how `T` in the example above is a true type (though unknown in the template definition).

The main advantage is that you can safely pass any type/class to variadic templates, while for C-style variadic you are limited to built-in types (including pointers). Using variadic template still requires some learning though.

Comment: May I ask HOW you are iterating over `args`? At which point in your code can you say `This is args[2] (third of args, however that is shown)?`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: It works like a cons-list (functional programming), that is, when I specify `T value, Args... args` I say capture the first item in `value` and put the rest in `args`. What is in `args` in unknown, and cannot be accessed directly, however I can pass it to another function here `printf(s, args...);` (note the `...`), and at this point it will once again split the pack into head/tail, unless there is nothing left (the pack is empty), in which case the call is equivalent to `printf(s)` which matches the first overload.

Comment: @Shahbaz: It's not iteration, it's recursion: Note the nested `printf` call with fewer arguments. Template programming has a very "functional" flavour.

Comment: @Mattieu: The code is quite neat, but arguably it's much less of a *formatting* print now, because you have no control over how the arguments are formatted.

Comment: I see. However, doesn't the OP ask _how to access all the arguments_ rather than how to pass them to another function? For example if he wanted to actually write a function using those arguments (like another printf) and not just pass it around?

Comment: @Shahbaz: it does access all the arguments (in a recursive fashion), so I think that it answers the question. Whether the OP can wrap his mind around recursion and head/tail split is of course another method. I hope he can.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I didn't notice (And wouldn't expect) that the name of the template function itself was `printf`!

Comment: @Shahbaz: it's surprising :) `printf` being a well-known variadic function, this example (originally from Douglas Gregor I think) was how it could now be implemented in a type-safe manner thanks to variadic templates.

Comment: I expected it to be `myMethod` as the OP had written. Anyway, thanks for the answer.